# How to convert MySql subquery to HQL subquery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, subquery, hql

#### hello everyone I have this subquery in mysql working like a charm!

```
select count(a.veces)
from 
(
        select count(id_product) as veces
        from production_line 
        group by id_product
        having count(id_product) > 2 and count(id_product) < 6
)  as a
```

#### And im trying to pass it into the HQL syntax in Hibernate but Im getting a syntax error.. Here is my HQL subquery

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().
createQuery("select count(a.veces) from 
(select count(pl.idProduct) as veces from ProductionLine pl group by
pl.idProduct having count(pl.idProduct) > :mayor and count(pl.idProduct) < :menor) as a");
```

#### However im getting this exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

#### someone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create the alias a? Try passing only  :

select count(pl.idProduct) as veces from ProductionLine pl group by
pl.idProduct having count(pl.idProduct) > :mayor and count(pl.idProduct) < :menor

to createQuery method

Comment: that query doesn't do I wanna, I have to use the subquery to get the information I wanna see, some other advice? anyways Thank you

Comment: I really do not agree to this but you can try using native query and pass
select count(a.veces)
from 
(
        select count(id_product) as veces
        from production_line 
        group by id_product
        having count(id_product) > 2 and count(id_product) < 6
)  as a